# How to get place name that shown on Google maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to ask if there is a way that we can get the name of place that is shown on Google Maps.
[image]

Comment: You can get it by calling Google Place API. You need to implement Google Map in application and get Lat long by placing Marker over Map. By this lat long you can call google place API and get places from there.

Comment: Can you share the google place api for web? I am using this ```https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json``` and it didn’t give the right name

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: This api doesn’t give the name that shows on Google Map

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flutter package [flutter_google_places_hoc081098](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places_hoc081098). It uses the [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) and other web service APIs of Google Maps Platform.

Using the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places_hoc081098/example) from that package, I was able to get the name of the place that you are looking for. Please see screenshots below.[image]

Comment: These gives error in web. However i found a solution i just added CORS link before google places url

Comment: Good to know that!

Comment: Actually for web every api is giving same XMLHttpRequest error. Can you help me how to solve this without using CORS link

Comment: I haven't tried it in web yet

Comment: maybe you can try this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places_web. I haven't tried that but it seems fitting on your use case

Comment: I have used it also. I dont remember exactly but i think it was not giving the desired output or it was causing the same error